# require impressionist in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sti

**tl;dr;** In development env, I want to preload the model with `is_impressionable` from initializer (since it is using STI). But an error occurred during preload `undefined method is_impressionable`.

I've tried `require 'impressionist'` it doesn't work. How should I go about loading impressionist in initializer then?

**Long version** I've got a bunch of STIs models and want to add `is_impressionable` for them.

The code goes like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_impressionable counter_cache: true

  class << self
    attr_reader :child_classes
  end

  def self.inherited(child)
    @child_classes << child
    super
  end

  def self.select_options
    self.child_classes.map { |c| c.to_s }.sort
  end

  def self.child_classes
    @child_classes
  end

end
```

Then for `News` and `Article`

```
class News < Post
end

class Article < Post
end
```

To ensure that my select options work in development mode I need to preload my STI models I have this initializer `config/initializers/preload_sti_models.rb`

```
if Rails.env.development? 
  %w[post news article].each do |c|
    require_dependency File.join("app", "models", "#{c}.rb")
  end
end
```

Now the problem is it seems `is_impressionable` is not available when the initializing occurs. I've tried adding `require "impressionist"` in the `preload_sti_models.rb` and it doesn't help.

How should I require "impressionist" so that I can do the preloading?